# That would be fun to code, but how do I post that here?

Tags: discussion, moderation, questions, stackexchange

I have been looking through some of the questions and I believe they would be impossible without a custom coding solution (prove me wrong, I hate duplication of work, therefore, why I am here).  I am very new to this server stuff.  I look at a question like this:

[fail2ban custom action to permanent ban IPs from China](https://serverfault.com/questions/456382/fail2ban-custom-action-to-permanent-ban-ips-from-china)

and think to myself.  The fail2ban code isn't that large (well in comparison with something like apache) maybe this is a something I would like to put some time towards and generally improve the open-source community.

I would assume that an answer of "see my github" would be frowned upon here.  I can't take it to stack overflow since I am not asking a question nor would they support a question about how to configure fail2ban.

tl;dr;  How would I submit custom coding solution to fix problems here.

Note:  I am ignoring that the question would most likely be closed before I have a chance to finish.

Note 2: I have no idea how long it would take a patch to get into upstream, but I am assuming that it would be much too long for people who have immediate problems

Comment: Even better, contribute it back to fail2ban so that everyone can benefit from it.

Comment: Unrelated to "How do I post an answer like this", but for the particular question you're referencing [note the caveat in its answer](http://serverfault.com/a/456407/32986).  Custom coded solutions that work in the general case are great, but I wouldn't suggest posting solutions that help people *Do It Wrong* -- a well-meaning answer with a great piece of code might wind up just getting you downvoted and smacked around in the comments for encouraging a Bad Idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would like to code your own solution to the problems posted, you are welcome to do so. To post it here, simply explain that you coded something, link to it, and *most importantly* explain how the code solves the problem. We welcome links to your github (or any other repository), but make sure that the Answer you post here contains a whole *answer to the question* with the link. Posts that are just links will be removed per our SPAM policy.

Here is a perfect example: [Evan Anderson wrote a script to block RDS connections after failures](https://serverfault.com/a/43900/33417)